# not open a href in the same window (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jQuery code opened this href in new window. I would like to open this href in the same window, but this is not working. (Toggle the side)

```
jQuery('.dig-pub').on('click', function() {
  url = jQuery(this).parent().find('a').attr('href');

  // Remove this (opens new window)
  window.open(url);

  // Use below to open link in the same window
  //$(location).attr(url);

});
```

https://codepen.io/Kidkie/pen/gdaJjZ

Comment: Try this one `window.open("https://www.youraddress.com","_self")`

Comment: Try `window.location.href = url;`

Comment: Plz visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Use  `window.location.href=url` code instead of `window.open(url);

Answer (score 0):

In fact to open the url in the same window you does to use the   window.location like that :

```
                jQuery('.dig-pub').on('click', function() {
                    url = jQuery(this).parent().find('a').attr('href');
                            window.location.href = url;
                                    });
```